# Selenium Python - Trying to driver.execute_script but get "None" while testing background-image

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium-webdriver, execute-script

I'm trying to test a background-image with Selenium. It doesn't have `<img>` tag, it have this html code (it is banner from https://openweather.co.uk/products page):

```
<div class="current-img white-text half-section-right main-section-desktop"></div>
```

and [this CSS styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgSpt.png)

This JavaScript code works well in DevTools console:

```
const image = new Image(); 
image.src = 'https://openweather.co.uk/themes/openweather_b2b/assets/img/forecast-banner.jpg';
image.onload = function(){
const imageWidth = this.width; 
const imageHeight = this.height;
console.log('Width:', imageWidth, 'Height:', imageHeight);
};
```

But how to implement this JS code to `driver.execute_script` and pass `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` back to Python code?

If I just pass this code into `driver.execute_script("here")` and print it - I got `None`.
If replace last line with `return('Width:', imageWidth, 'Height:', imageHeight);` I got `None` too.

And in general - how to return data from `driver.execute_script` back to Python correctly?
For example `driver.execute_script("return console.log('Hi');")` gives `None` too.

Comment: Instead of complicating everything, you could simply use element.value_of_css_property(property_name) to get the css style values of <div> tag & verify with your expected values. Documentation for this method usage can be found in https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property